# Introduction to fast algorithms for time–frequency analysis

Tags: algorithms, time-frequency, reference-request

I had preliminary knowledge of digital signal processing from Oppenheim's [Discrete-Time Signal Processing](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1795494) and is studying time-frequency analysis now. May someone suggest introductory reference (textbook, website, review paper...) for the fast algorithm aspects of time–frequency analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in discrete linear systems (either time-frequency or time-scale), you could invest in multirate filter banks, that provide tools for computing, optimizing, etc, such as the polyphase matrix or the lifting scheme. A  tutorial paper is

- [Multirate digital filters, filter banks, polyphase networks and Applications: A Tutorial](http://www.systems.caltech.edu/dsp/ppv/papers/ProcIEEEmultirateTUTExtra.pdf) by P. P. Vaidyanathan.

An earlier reference is

- [Frequency-domain and multirate adaptive filtering](http://users.isy.liu.se/en/rt/fredrik/spcourse/multirate.pdf) by J. Shynk.

However, additional notes could be helpful on you side whether you need:

- specificities: amount of memory, real-time constraints, quantization
- analysis only or analysis/synthesis
- linear or nonlinear time-frequency
- discrete or discrete approximation to continuous
- fast in number of operations, convergence, or using hardware capabilities (finite-precision, approximate versions, etc.)

If you do consider sliding windows for Fourier analysis, this can be cast into the framework of modulated [complex  oversampled filterbanks](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2009.2023947), for which fast algorithms do exist, see for instance:

- [Fast Implementation of Oversampled Modulated Filter Banks](https://doi.org/10.1049/el:20001068), 2000, S. Weiss and R.W. Stewart

Comment: The reference is very useful. Thank you. I am looking for analysis only, linear time-frequency, discrete, fast in number of operations algorithm. The specificities is quite arbitrary as I am a greenhorn and is now focusing on the basic part of fast algorithm.